# Rename photo name if already uploaded [with same name] in PHP

Tags: php, image-uploading

I have tried to solve this problem . But i could not solve this . 
Each time new photo replace the old one if same name :( 
Here is my code

```
      $uploads_dir = '/photo/';

      echo $_FILES["photo"]["name"]; 
      echo $_FILES["photo"]["size"];
      echo $_FILES["photo"]["type"];
      $pname = $_FILES["photo"]["name"]; 
      $tname=$_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"];

      $name = pathinfo($_FILES['photo']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
      $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['photo']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

       $increment = ''; //start with no suffix

       while(file_exists($name . $increment . '.' . $extension)) {
         $increment++;
     $pname = $name . $increment . '.' . $extension;

        }
        move_uploaded_file($tname, $uploads_dir.$pname);
```

My desired output is like this 
if i upload image with name "new.jpg" 3 time ... 
these image will not overwrite one another... these will be stored like new.jpg , new1.jpg ,new2.jpg

Comment: Do you want to rename it? Or what are you supposed to do?

Comment: you're increment is on a string instead of an int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
  $uploads_dir = '/photo/';

  echo $_FILES["photo"]["name"]; 
  echo $_FILES["photo"]["size"];
  echo $_FILES["photo"]["type"];
  $pname = $_FILES["photo"]["name"]; 
  $tname=$_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"];

  $name = pathinfo($_FILES['photo']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
  $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['photo']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

   $increment = 0; 
   $pname = $name . '.' . $extension;
   while(is_file($uploads_dir.'/'.$pname)) {
     $increment++;
     $pname = $name . $increment . '.' . $extension;
   }
   move_uploaded_file($tname, $uploads_dir.'/'.$pname);
```

Comment: But why is_file instead of file_exists ?

Comment: cuz file_exists works also with directories.
"Checks whether a file or directory exists." http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: but is_file checks if element exists and if it is a file

Comment: "Returns TRUE if the filename exists and is a regular file, FALSE otherwise."  http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.is-file.php